# UITextView will shorten text?

Tags: ios, uitextview, textkit

How to know wether `UITextView` will shorten text because lack of space? I know I can calculate with `boundingRectWithSize` and `sizeThatFit`, but what if `exclusionPaths` of the `UITextView` is changed. I want lay out string in a polygon, and increase polygon size, until string laid out without shortening. Any idea, how can get a bool return, wether current setup will shorten?

```
self.tv.textContainer.exclusionPaths = myArrayOfBezierPaths;
```

Comment: [Did you read this?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19917287/312312)

Answer (score 2):

```
func isSizeFitForTextView() -> Bool{
    let layoutManager = self.textView.layoutManager
    let glyphIndex = layoutManager.glyphIndexForCharacter(at:( self.textView.text as NSString).length)

    let range = layoutManager.truncatedGlyphRange(inLineFragmentForGlyphAt: glyphIndex)

    return range.location != NSNotFound
}
```